# How to configure visual studio 2010 with opencv cvblobs library

Tags: c, opencv, computer-vision

I'm having difficulty of installation/ compilation of cvBlob into OpenCV Microsoft Visual Studio 2010 in WINDOW. I understood that there is a installation guide work on linux but I couldn't find how it can be done in Window.

I would appreciate if someone may provide me the installation guide in WINDOW as I found that cvBlob is very useful for my project.Thanks

Comment: I think the Operating System you are talking about is named **WINDOWS**.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For the moment there is no pre-built [cvBlob](http://cvblob.googlecode.com/files/cvblob-0.10.3-src.zip) for Visual Studio, so you are going to have to compile it yourself.

So before you start, make sure you have [OpenCV](http://ufpr.dl.sourceforge.net/project/opencvlibrary/opencv-win/2.3.1/OpenCV-2.3.1-win-superpack.exe) installed in your computer.

**[Download](http://www.cmake.org/files/v2.8/cmake-2.8.6-win32-x86.exe) [CMake for Windows](http://www.cmake.org/cmake/help/runningcmake.html). CMake creates the Visual Studio project files that are needed to compile cvBlob.**

Once you open **cmake-gui**, fill in the edit boxes *"Where is the source code"* and *"Where to build the binaries"* accordingly (adjust these to your settings):

- C:/Documents and Settings/user/Meus documentos/Downloads/cvblob-0.10.3-src/cvblob
- C:/Documents and Settings/user/Meus documentos/Downloads/cvblob-0.10.3-src/cvblob/build

Note: the **build** folder was created manually.

Click on button **Configure** to check for dependencies (CMake will try to find OpenCV on your computer) and then on **Generate** so it can generate the Visual Studio project files.

From here on it's the standard compilation procedures.

Answer (score 3):

karlphillip's answer is correct, and you should follow it. Be advised, however, that if you're building the files using VS 2010, a few of them will fail and return this error:

```
LINK : fatal error LNK1104: cannot open file '..\lib\Debug\cvblob.lib'
```

To get around this, add the following to your cvblob.h file:

```
#define EXPORT __declspec (dllexport)
```

In the extern "C" block below that, add EXPORT before every function. For example:

```
EXPORT double cvContourPolygonArea(CvContourPolygon const *p);
```

After running into this error myself, I found the explanation here (which I adapted to make this post; all credit belongs to this link's author): https://code.google.com/p/cvblob/issues/detail?id=34

Just something you might want to watch out for. Hope it helps!