# OpenCV : Difficulty in working with cvBlobs Library

Tags: visual-studio-2010, opencv, cvblobslib

I am a beginner in `OpenCV2.3` on Windows7 and `Visual Studio2010` and finding a tough time(confused rather due to several version available in google) in installing the blob library. I am aware that there are several posts on SO itself dealing with this question. So, kindly bear with this question. These are the steps that I did.

1. Downloaded the library from [Grossman's blob detection library](http://tech.groups.yahoo.com/group/OpenCV/message/90124)
2. Extracted the zipped folder
3. Created a New Visual Studio 2010 blank project `C:\Users\Admin\Documents\Visual Studio 2010\Projects\Blob` after reading [Link1](http://www.technical-recipes.com/2011/object-detection-using-the-opencv-cvblobslib-libraries/)
4. Copied the two .cpp files from Step(1) under `Source` folder and copied the include.h under `Header` folder in VS2010. Then, I included the Additional Libraries and Other Dependencies which we normally do to run any OpenCV program.
5. This is where I am lost >> Followed [Link2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8503748/how-to-configure-visual-studio-2010-with-opencv-cvblobs-library). In my version of Cmake2.8.7 under *Where is the source code* I have `C:/OpenCV2.3/opencv/opencv` and under *Where to build libraries*, I have `C:/Users/Shreya/Downloads/OpenCV2.3`. What should be done now?

Would be highly grateful for a detailed explanation.